# Dictionary and list value processing

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a code which will produce the dict as follows:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'b0116ce25cad4106becbbddfffa61a1c': [u'demo_ins1', u'2530.0'], u'1578f81703ec4bbaa1d548532c922ab9': [u'new_ins_1', u'1750.0', u'new_tenant_ins', u'2520.0']})
```

Code:

```
# inilialize necessary dict
dict_compute = defaultdict(list)

for tenants,instances in tenant_id_dict.iteritems():

        for single_ins in instances:
                compute_value_for_instance = ck.reports.get_total(tenant_id=tenants, service='compute', instance_id=single_ins)
                dict_compute[tenants].append(single_ins)
                dict_compute[tenants].append(compute_value_for_instance)
                print dict_compute
```

Dictionary which is combination of tenant_id, Instance_name and cost.

I need to keep a relation between each other.

I need the result should be as follows:

```
{u'b0116ce25cad4106becbbddfffa61a1c': [u'demo_ins1' : u'2530.0']
```

Ie: That is for each tenant it should be displaying the instance name(demo) and cost(2530.0) as needed.

Need a better way for the same, Which one is best List or Dict.

I should be able to fetch and process if needed.

I am OK with anything(List or Dict) I just need to keep a relation.

Someone have a look and let me know the solution or suggestions.

Comment: I think `:` in your Should be result `[u'demo_ins1' : u'2530.0']` clears it quite well that you need a dict. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better try initializing a list and appending dictionary to it as below-

```
from collections import defaultdict
# inilialize necessary dict
dict_compute = defaultdict(list)

for tenants,instances in tenant_id_dict.iteritems():
    for single_ins in instances:
        compute_value_for_instance = ck.reports.get_total(tenant_id=tenants, service='compute', instance_id=single_ins)
        dict_compute[tenants].append({single_ins:compute_value_for_instance})
        print dict_compute
```

EDIT- If you need oneliner then below would work no need of using `defaultdict`-

```
dict_compute = {tenants:[{single_ins:ck.reports.get_total(tenant_id=tenants, service='compute', instance_id=single_ins)} for single_ins in instances] for tenants,instances in tenant_id_dict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Shouldn't dict inside defaultdict be better? Why need list and then append single key:value dicts to it?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir  Consider this line `for single_ins in instances:`

Comment: Can be like { single_ins: compute_value_for_instance for single_ins in instances }

Comment: @MuhammadTahir i tried to maintain OP's code a much as possible- may be it is needed for debugging purpose see `print dict_compute`. Nonetheless i edited the answer.